# Suppress stacktrace logging in spring kafka container errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using a simple spring boot app to consume from a kafka topic and configured my container factory with SeekToCurrentErrorHandler

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                                                 ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        ...
        final SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((consumerRecord, e) -> log.error("Error reading from topic: {}, Offset: {}, Partition: {}, Key: {}, Exception: {}",
                consumerRecord.topic(),
                consumerRecord.offset(),
                consumerRecord.partition(),
                consumerRecord.key(),
                ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e)), new FixedBackOff(1000L, 3L));
        seekToCurrentErrorHandler.removeNotRetryableException(DeserializationException.class); /*This line is intentional as its easier for me to simulate the issue this way.*/
        factory.setErrorHandler(seekToCurrentErrorHandler);
        ...
}
```

The `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` is printing the entire stacktrace of any exception (DeserializationException in this case) that occurs before the `poll()` returns to the listener.

This is resulting in a ton of logs entries. Is there a way to suppress this behavior. I tried this tip from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.9/reference/html/#error-handlers) but it is only changing the log level and not suppressing the stacktrace.

```
/**
 * Set the level at which the exception thrown by this handler is logged.
 * @param logLevel the level (default ERROR).
 */
public void setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level logLevel) {
    ...
}
```

I upgraded all dependencies to the latest versions.

- Spring boot - 2.5.7
- Spring - 5.3.13
- Spring Kafka - 2.7.9
- Kafka Clients - 2.8.1

StackTrace:

```
2021-11-19 12:37:53.047  INFO 560 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-MyListenerGroup-Testing-1, groupId=MyListenerGroup-Testing] Resetting offset for partition some-topic-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=7763, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[someserver.testing.net:9092 (id: 30 rack: null)], epoch=8}}.
2021-11-19 12:37:54.554 DEBUG 560 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Received: 2 records
2021-11-19 12:37:55.570  INFO 560 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-MyListenerGroup-Testing-1, groupId=MyListenerGroup-Testing] Seeking to offset 7763 for partition some-topic-0
2021-11-19 12:37:55.578 ERROR 560 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 27
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:206) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2371) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2240) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2154) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2036) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1709) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1276) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1268) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1163) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 27
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2387) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.checkDeser(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2434) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2302) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2229) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 27
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserializationException(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:216) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:191) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1386) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:133) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1617) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1453) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:686) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:637) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1303) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.poll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1414) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1251) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 27
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found com.foo.bar.CustomerRelationshipStateNew, expecting com.foo.bar.CustomerRelationshipStateNew, missing required field Status
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:309) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:86) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readFieldOrder(ResolvingDecoder.java:128) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:239) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readArray(GenericDatumReader.java:298) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:183) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:136) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.read(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:351) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.5.6.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:99) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.5.6.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:78) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.5.6.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.5.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:188) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1386) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:133) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1617) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1453) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:686) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:637) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1303) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1237) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.poll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1414) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1251) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1163) [spring-kafka-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292]
```

Comment: Can you show some logs, please, to determine which exactly place is emitting undesired stack traces?

Comment: @ArtemBilan updated my original post with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I see now.

So, I'd suggest you to implement your own `RemainingRecordsErrorHandler` with delegation to that `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` calling `super` in this method:

```
public void handle(Exception thrownException, @Nullable List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,
        Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
```

So, you can `catch` all the exception from that delegate and re-throw them whatever way you need, e.g. ditching those stack traces from the `KafkaException`s.

Comment: Is this what you are recommending in my error handler implementation?
`@Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        try {
            this.seekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(thrownException, records, consumer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }`

Comment: Well, close. Probably not `ignore` since you still need to re-throw something for the listener container to be happy.

Comment: Do you recommend implementing `RemainingRecordsErrorHandler` or `ContainerAwareErrorHandler` since RemainingRecordsErrorHandler does not have handle method with `container` in the parameters and any call to `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(Exception thrownException, @Nullable List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,Consumer<?, ?> consumer)` will go to `ContainerAwareErrorHandler.handle(Exception thrownException, @Nullable List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer)` which will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: See this one `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler extends FailedRecordProcessor implements ContainerAwareErrorHandler`. So, indeed you need to implement a `ContainerAwareErrorHandler` to be able to delegate properly.

Comment: But wont rethrowing the Exception in `MyErrorHandler.handle` make the ListenerContainer print the stacktrace again.

Comment: Right, that's the point. You can modify an exception you are going to re-throw. I thought your point was to not have too much. So, just re-throw a message. Or you can do whatever you need. Sorry, this was only the way you can reuse seek functionality and have a control over an exception from there.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean; you already pointed to the `setLogLevel` method but the log shows as ERROR; if you set the level to DEBUG, the stack trace won't be logged (unless DEBUG logging is enabled).